Find the limit of the given sequence $x_{n+1} = x_n (2 − dx_n )$

Consider $$x_{n+1} = x_n (2 − dx_n )$$
where $d \ne 0$ is a given number. Assume that the sequence converges
to a number $x^∗ \ne 0$.
(a) Determine the limit $x^∗$ .
(b) Show that the local convergence rate is quadratic, that is, the
rate p = 2.

The first I have no idea how to solve, since the question does not specific whether $n\to \infty$ or $n\to 0$. Does that question make sense to you?
The second should follow the form:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|x_{n+1}\|}{\|x_{n}\|^2}= \frac{\|2x_n-dx_n^2\|}{\|x_n||^2}$$
that gives
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\|x_n\|\|(2-dx_n)\|}{\|x_n^2\|}=\frac{\|(2-dx_n)\|}{\|x_n\|}=\frac{2}{\|x_n\|}+\frac{\|dx_n\|}{\|x_n\|}=d$$
How should this give 2?
A hint on a) is also greatly appreciated!
Thanks

$x^{}= x^{}(2-dx^{})$ so $x^{}=0$ or $\frac  2 d$.

Can you see why the second option is ruled out?

What do you mean by second option=

$x^{*}=\frac  2 d$ is ruled out because it would lead to $x_{n+1} \to 0$.

I see, with the rate  of 2, that is ruled out.

The fixed-point equation gives
$$
x=x(2-dx)
$$
so that either $x_*=0$ or $x_*=1/d$.
For the convergence explore the behavior of the sequence $y_n=1-dx_n$. This is closely related to computing the limit of
$$\frac{|x_{n+1}-x_*|}{|x_n-x_*|^2}=|d|\frac{|y_{n+1}|}{|y_n|^2},$$
which if it exists as a positive number confirms the quadratic convergence
One might also find out that the iteration is the Newton iteration for the function
$$f(x)=d-1/x,$$ which is quadratically convergent on a more general basis. This idea is usually applied for iterative approximate matrix inversion.

Thanks Lutz. About that second point, did you see that getting 2 is difficult, with that limit  formula?

Your limit formula is only valid for the limit $x_*=0$. Otherwise you need to consider this expression for the remainders $|x_n-1/d|$.

Great, thanks for the tip!!

Hi Lutz, I did the following $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{||x_{n+1}||}{||x_{n}||^2}= \frac{||2x_n-dx_n^2||}{||x_n-1||^2}\implies \frac{||2x_n||}{||x_n-1||^2}+\frac{||-dx_n^2||}{||x_n-1||^2}$$ This may be wrong, since I don't get 2.

Clear the board and start again. Also go back to the definition of the Q-convergence order.

Hi Lutz, Q convergence is only listed in peer reviewed papers, rather heavy reading, can't find any example. https://www.math.drexel.edu/~tolya/convergence . With this reading I get: $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n^p}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x_n(2-dx_n)}{(x_n-\frac1d)^2}$$

No, the idea and definition of Q-convergence is not difficult, you are using it in a distorted version. To prove Q-convergence for some new method can indeed require some elaborate proof strategies. That the Newton method at simple roots has order 2 is well-known and not that complicated to prove, but it requires clean calculations.

I have no idea how to do this
